# Clean Magento 2 installation terribly slow

Tags: magento2

I did a fresh installation of `Magento 2.3.1` (standard theme) and it's terribly slow. The server should be fine because non-optimized M1 installations running good.

I already did the obvious optimizations:

```
- Minify css enabled
- Minify js enabled
- Minify html enabled
- Merge css enabled
- Merge js enabled
- Bundle js disabled
- Sign Static Files enabled
- Use Flat Catalog
```

I did not

- use Varnish (because I can't cache prices since I will have different prices for different customers).
- change mode to production (`when I do bin/magento deploy:show:mode I get Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later. Please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html`)

What I noticed is that after I first visited the page, it gets a little bit faster. I guess the pages are cached. But after `~1hr` without any interaction it's very slow again.

**Is that normal? What could I do? Thanks**

Comment: please switch to production mode since css and js minification is not enabled in developer mode. Your site will be slow in development mode which is normal

Comment: Ok, thanks. But as I said, when I try to bin/magento deploy:show:mode or bin/magento deploy:set:mode production all I'm getting is "Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later. Please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html" 

Not sure what taht means. That message does not help me since I'm on PHP 7.1.2

Comment: Is your goal to go live with M2.3.1 or to keep it in developer mode and build module/theme?

Comment: I just wanted to check the best possible performance of M2 (standard theme) under my circumstances. I was shocked how slow it was, that's why I asked if there's any trick I missed. Still trying to set it to production mode since my server only has PHP 7.1.2 right now. But I will update next week. I hope production mode will speed up the site significantly. I will go back to developer mode then and build the page.

Comment: Ok, I now set it to production mode but to be honest, it did not get any faster. So I'm out of ideas. My server is running SSDs and has enough RAM according to my provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move the site to production mode you have to upgrade your PHP since Magento 2.3.1 is compatible with PHP 7.2.X Please find the link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.1OpenSource.html https://prnt.sc/n4na5a.

Comment: Thanks. I thought 7.1.2 would be enough. And production mode will really speed up the site significantly?

Comment: Yes it will. You can find the information about various Magento Modes in this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html. If this answer solved your question please accept it as the answer to your question as it will be helpful for others. Thanks